# Bash insert heredoc contents directly to specific place in output file w/o temporary file?

Tags: bash, heredoc

Is it possible to insert heredoc contents directly to specific row in output file without temp file ?

```
cat <<-EOT > tmp.txt
    some string
            another string

            and another one
EOT
sed -i '10 r tmp.txt' outputfile && rm tmp.txt
```

I've been using something like this , but I'd prefer to avoid needing `tmp.txt`.

Comment: I'm not following what it is this script is doing. Particularly the `sed` line. I'm no seder though. What is `'10 r tmp.txt'`?

Comment: the `r` command reads a file at the specified address.

Comment: Writes heredoc contents in tmp.txt . sed inserts tmp.txt in outputfile row 10  in between existing text .

Comment: Somewhat surprising that `-` isn't a valid argument for `r`, although `sed` reading the file to *edit* from standard input is probably too common to make this kind of overlap worth supporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires some support from your file system, but

```
sed -i '10 r /dev/stdin' outputfile <<EOF
  additional
  lines
EOF
```

would work. However, if you are specifying the text directly in your script rather than a real file, the `a\` command would probably be more appropriate:

```
sed -i '10a\
additional\
lines\
' outputfile
```

Comment: Keep @glennjackman's `ed` answer in mind, though. `ed` is really the right tool for editing files, with `sed` being more appropriate for *streams* (that's what the `s` stands for). `ed file.txt`, but `... | sed '...' | ...`.

Comment: On OpenBSD, you must add a \ after lines  and ' outputfile on a other line.

Comment: Better ! Should have mentioned that the code to be inserted is in the script .

Comment: Oh, right. I tested this on macOS, but didn't look closely enough at the output to see a missing newline.

Answer (score 4):

`ed` might be a good choice

```
# create a test file
seq 15 > file

# save the heredoc contents in a variable
new=$(cat <<-EOT
    some string
            another string

            and another one
EOT
)
# note the close parenthesis must **not** be on the same line as the heredoc word

# add the contents into the file
ed file <<EOF
10i
$new
.
wq
EOF

cat file
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
some string
        another string

        and another one
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

You could merge the two heredocs to save a step:

```
ed file <<-EOF
    10i
    some string
            another string

            and another one
    .
    wq
EOF
```